# AngularJS scope.apply causes error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, apply

I have this function which fetches data from the DB and updates scope's values.

```
$scope.loadFromDB = function(){
              console.log("loadFromDB function");
              $http({
                      url: '/getData',
                      method: "GET",
                  })
                  .then(function(response) {
                          // success
                          var data = JSON.parse(response.data)
                          data = JSON.parse(data.data)
                          $scope.gridDataDayData = data.dayData;
                          $scope.gridDataKlasoveNames = data.klasoveNames;
                          $scope.gridDataNumOfRows = data.numOfRows;
                          $scope.$apply();
                      },
                      function(response) { // optional
                          // failed
                          console.log("get unsuccessful");
                      });
            };
```

When I run this though I get

```
error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

I can not figure out how to fix this. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: What happens without `$scope.$apply();` ?

Comment: It does not update the grid data

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.gridDataDayData = data.dayData;
  $scope.gridDataKlasoveNames = data.klasoveNames;
  $scope.gridDataNumOfRows = data.numOfRows;
});`

Comment: Which grid are you using?

Comment: `$http` already call digest internally, there is no need to call `$apply` in that. Probably you should try inspecting your data and see if there is a need to `JSON.parse`, because normally angular does that automatically.

Comment: provide more info like why you are applying digest cycle? What happens when you remove digest cycle? What are you expecting from this code?

Comment: You guys are right. There was a problem with the data. When I fixed it and removed $scope.$apply everything worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trigger the *digest cycle* because you are inside the angular life cycle... it is already running. 
A manual triggering is needed when you are outside from the angular way: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: if there are no updates, the error resides elsewhere but not here... your script is a bit confusing, for example you don't need to parse as a json because angular does it for you... but is correct and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.data)                                           
data = JSON.parse(data.data) and $scope.$apply()
```

and

`$scope.$apply();`